# How to exclude project from .gitignore

Tags: git, visual-studio, gitignore

I have a Visual Studio solution, inside my solution I created a new project named: `MyProject.Log`

I committed but saw there is nothing to commit.

Then I opened my .gitignore file and saw a ***.log** and **[Ll]og/**. So Im sure that why `MyProject.Log` folder is exluded.

> What do I have to add in my .gitignore file so my new project is added but everything inside is filtered with the .gitignore patterns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `!MyProject.log` to the .gitignore file. The `!` reverses the exclusion. Put it after the pattern that excludes it.